# Facebook Authentication Token

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm building an app that requires a Facebook Authentication Token.

Google'ing it I end up on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

This names the following tokens:

- User Access Token
- App Access Token
- Page Access Token
- Client Token

Are any of these a Facebook Authentication Token?

If not, how do you get one?

Comment: Yes - all of the tokens you referenced are used as authentication tokens. Different tokens authenticate different entities - User access tokens perform actions on behalf of a user, App access tokens perform actions on behalf of an application, etc...

Comment: The link you posted contains information on how to obtain each of these tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this tool here:

https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/access-token/

Comment: it says - Due to some sudden Facebook changes the directions below will no longer work for new Facebook apps